# how taxes work on steam?

Tags: steam

I have been developing a game for some time thinking of distributing it on steam.

I had a question about taxes. And is that since I am not a resident of the United States, I made my tax questionnaire and I have a 10% rate for the sale of video games due to the treaty with my country.

And was I reading that every country has a tax? special? (VAT) or something like that, for example United Kingdom 20%

Which means that if I sell a game of 10 (€) I think this should happen

**Scenario 1:**

```
1 Unit Sale  ---  10.00 €
- (VAT)            1.66 € 
-------------------------
Sale w/o VAT       8.33 €
- Steam 30%        2.50 €
-------------------------
S w/o Steam cut    5.83 €
- ISR USA (10%)    0.58 €
-------------------------
Sale revenue       5.25 €  (Less taxes from my country later calculated, this amount is the one deposited by steam)
```

Scenario 1 considers that each subtraction is made on a non-total balance

Or

**Scenario 2:**

The percentage is fixed on the total sale

```
1 Unit Sale  ---  10.00 €
- (VAT)            1.66 € 
- Steam 30%        3.00 €
- ISR USA (10%)    1.00 €
-------------------------
Sale revenue       4.33 € (Less taxes from my country later calculated, this amount is the one deposited by steam)
```

Does anyone know how this situation is handled ?, or where could I get more information?

Comment: Please don't make false edits to bump a question. If it's not getting the attention you want, try to make substantial edits that add more information to the question. For questions about a privately run service, asking the company that runs that service directly is always your best bet.